# Get visible rows from org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer

Tags: java, eclipse, jface, tableviewer

I'm using org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer in one of my projects. I need to export the visible rows of my table in a CSV file. Saying visible, I mean the rows a user can see after the table has been filtered. But I can't understand how I can get the rows, I didn't find any appropriate method. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct method.

One way is to get the `TableItem` array of the underlying `Table` that `TableViewer` uses. The table will only contain the visible items. The data in the table item is the element from your content provider:

```
TableItem [] items = viewer.getTable().getItems();
for (final TableItem item : items) {
   Object data = item.getData();
   // TODO data is the element from the content provider
}
```